# What kind of map were they playing in the BLAST.tv Major, Champions Stage: Quarterfinals Day 1?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

[image: Yekindar is playing BLAST.tv Major challenge]

Timestamp from Twitch — **BLAST.tv Major, Champions Stage: Quarterfinals Day 1** at 6:49:05:
https://www.twitch.tv/videos/1822964337?t=6h49m05s

I tried to search through community workshop practice maps (I assume it has been taken from there), yet didn't manage to find the exact one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a de_dust2 practice map.

https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=285709994

This timestamp matches the screenshot:

[image]